# Why can't I switch between open windows in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04

I recently did a clean install of 12.04 (Ubuntu flavour) onto various PCs and not a single one is capable of switching between a program's open windows in Unity the way you could in 11.10 (by double clicking the launcher). Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be clicking the small white arrow next to the launcher icon.

Hope this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the new version of Unity only shows windows from the same workspace (viewport).
The decision can be seen [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/689733) (see comment #3).

Comment: I am only using a single workspace.